# ColdFusion Object to String

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I'm really new to ColdFusion and am trying to pull data out of the database and send it to an email function I have created.

```
myQry = new Query();
myQry.setSQL("select * from stocknotifications LEFT JOIN options ON stocknotifications.stocknotification_id = options.option_id  ORDER BY stocknotification_id DESC LIMIT 1 "); //set query


qryRes = myQry.execute();

writedump(qryRes.getResult(), false);

Mail = variables.NotificationService.newMail();
Mail.setTo("bfrench@destinationcms.co.uk");
Mail.setSubject( "New Stock Request" );

// render body with layout which uses the rc.emailView
Mail.setBody(ToString(qryRes.getResult()));
variables.NotificationService.sendMail( Mail );
```

My writeDump() works and shows the last item in table. The only problem is I can't pass it into setBody() without it throwing an error.

> *Can't cast Complex Object Type Query to String
>   Use Built-In-Function "serialize(Query):String" to create a String from Query*

Any ideas?

Comment: serialjson() ? or maybe even `<cfwddx action="cfml2wddx"`. More likely you want to build an html table that has the results of your query and have that be a part of the body of your email

Comment: qryRes.getResult() returns a query object that can't be converted to a string automatically. You have to convert it to json or some other format (such as html) to use it as plain text.

Comment: They could just `writedump()` it to the email though, if they didn't want to write their own formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the error message you received, you could actually replace toString with serialize and you'd be good to go.

If all you want is the data going to e-mail without caring about presentation, **quick and dirty,** you might want to try `SerializeJSON()`; it will convert the `query` into a `JSON` string with `COLUMNS` and `DATA`:

```
Mail.setBody(SerializeJSON(qryRes.getResult()));
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is with cfsavecontent.  I'm not sure if there is a script version of this so I'll show you how to use is with tags. You already have a query result named qryRes.

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "eMailBody">
<cfoutput query = "qryRes">
#field1#, #field2# etc
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Then for mail function, you can do this:

```
mail.setBody(emailBody);
```

If you want to send your email in html format, put the appropriate html tags inside the cfsavecontent block.  Otherwise, pay attention to the carraige returns of your source code.  They get included in the variable produced by cfsavecontent.  For the code sample above, you will get 3 blank lines at the top of the body, and the data rows will be double spaced.

Comment: CFScript version is: `savecontent variable="sText" { WriteOutput("Blah"); }`